# Calculating total items in each quarter by the last day of each month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that have multiple records of items with creation date over the years. I need to count all items that was created in last day of each month and then get the calculation for its quarter for each year by summing all items in its months.
the table is as below:

| item_code | Creation_date | location | Item_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

for example: Jan 31  created items + Feb 28 created items + Mar 31 created items. year of 2023 = 500 and April 30 + May 31 + Jun 30 = 200 etc.
Noticing that February is sometimes 28 and sometimes 29 depending on the year
( only count the items created on the last day of the month, not all those during that month)

the result is

| total items | Year | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 2023 | 1 |
| 200 | 2023 | 2 |

Thank you.

Comment: You only count the items created on the last day of the month, not all those during that month? Please edit your question to include sample data (including for other days) and the expected result for that data; and preferably what you have tried and exactly where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(creation_date, 'Q'), 'YYYY') AS year,
       TO_CHAR(TRUNC(creation_date, 'Q'), 'Q') AS quarter,
       COUNT(item_code) AS total_items
FROM   table_name
WHERE  creation_date >= LAST_DAY(TRUNC(creation_date))
GROUP BY TRUNC(creation_date, 'Q')
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (item_code, Creation_date, location, Item_type) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-01-01', 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-01-31' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-02-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-02-28' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-04-28' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-04-30' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-04-30' + INTERVAL '2' HOUR, 'x', 'y' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| YEAR | QUARTER | TOTAL_ITEMS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1 | 2 |
| 2023 | 2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XNp0UMjt)